# Jspdf.js is dropping first space in text in Label from doc.html

Tags: html, jquery, jspdf

Good day. I have a HTML code being sent to jspdf.js by using doc.html. It generates the HTML to PDF but with one problem. It truncates the text inside my label tags by removing every first space in the label text. And sometimes other spaces aswell.

Here is a visual sample of how the HTMl looks in the Browser frontend.

[HTML frontend view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaNXZ.png)

This is how the code is layed out.

```
<div style="text-align: left; display: block;" id="sqAn5k"><label style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px;">Indication : </label><label class="topcoat-checkbox" style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px; margin-right:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_USKR77" style="display:inline-block" value="Rectal bleeding" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"><div class="topcoat-checkbox__checkmark" style="margin-top: 8px; opacity: 1;"></div></label><label style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px;">Rectal bleeding</label></div>

<div style="text-align: left; display: block;" id="l8a4Pq"><label style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px;">Indication : </label><label class="topcoat-checkbox" style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px; margin-right:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_1LowCz" style="display:inline-block" value="Change in bowel habit" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"><div class="topcoat-checkbox__checkmark" style="margin-top: 8px; opacity: 1;"></div></label><label style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px;">Change in bowels habit</label></div>

<div style="text-align: left; display: block;" id="otxoKR"><label style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px;">Indication : </label><label class="topcoat-checkbox" style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px; margin-right:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_Rp0G7G" style="display:inline-block" value="Abdominal pain" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"><div class="topcoat-checkbox__checkmark" style="margin-top: 8px; opacity: 1;"></div></label><label style="display:inline-block; line-height: 32px; height:32px;">Abdominal pain</label></div>
```

And this is how the PDF is exported.
Where clone is the variable where html is saved in..
and divWidth is the a4 page width.
blob is passed to server side and in php file is generated by file_get_content.

```
doc.html(clone.html(), {
    callback: function(doc) {

var blob = doc.output('blob');
 },
       windowWidth: divWidth,
       width:196,
       x: 2,
       y: -1,
    });
```

My pdf ends up as follow.
[PDF sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmxMW.png)

Any suggestion on this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. Thank you for the feedback. I have tested with changing the fonts and detected that the css character-spacing should be set to 0. This was previously not set. The HTML viewed correctly so there were no need to set character-spacing. This however corrected the issue for me. Thank you –